# After effects not showing TWO composition panels

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I am using after effect 2020. Suddenly composition panel splits into two part. I do not understand how does this happen.

I want one compotation panel like old times. please help :'(

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Video editing is off-topic here. Sorry about that. Try Video Production Stack Exchange instead.

Comment: Thank you Billy.